# Using Cilk Plus with MinGW-w64 (gcc 4.9.2)?

Tags: c++, mingw, mingw-w64, cilk-plus

Is it possible to use **Cilk Plus** with **MinGW-w64** (x86_64-4.9.2-posix-sjlj-rt_v3-rev0)?

When I dont use `-fcilkplus` option, compiler gives me an error `"-fcilkplus must be enabled to use '_Cilk_spawn'"` - so obviously it recognizes extensions keyword. On the other side there`s not any trace of `'cilk.h'` nor any other file containing `"cilk"` in it`s name, in the compilers install folder.

If compiled with options `-fcilkplus -lcilkrts`, I get an Error:

`"libcilkrts.spec: No such file or directory"`.

Compiled from *Code::Blocks*, Errors log:

```
undefined reference to `__cilkrts_enter_frame_1'|
undefined reference to `__cilkrts_save_fp_ctrl_state'|
undefined reference to `__cilkrts_save_fp_ctrl_state'|
undefined reference to `__cilkrts_sync'|
undefined reference to `__cilkrts_rethrow'|
undefined reference to `__cilkrts_save_fp_ctrl_state'|
undefined reference to `__cilkrts_sync'|
undefined reference to `__cilkrts_rethrow'|
undefined reference to `__cilkrts_leave_frame'|
undefined reference to `__cilkrts_save_fp_ctrl_state'|
undefined reference to `__cilkrts_sync'|
undefined reference to `__cilkrts_rethrow'|
undefined reference to `__cilkrts_leave_frame'|
undefined reference to `__cilkrts_enter_frame_fast_1'|
undefined reference to `__cilkrts_leave_frame'|
||=== Build failed: 15 error(s), 2 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

MinGW and TDM-MinGW both use older gcc versions(4.8 series), so they don`t recognize `cilk` keywords.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that MinGW on windows doesn't support Intel Cilk.